# Multiple plots from a single pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Here are the fields in the dataframe

```
date        dept      residual
4/22/17      8         100.00
4/29/17      8         23.34
 ....        8         ...
 ....        8         ...

4/22/17     12         10.10
....        12         ...
....        12         ...
```

I want to plot the residuals for each department with the date being the x-axis, and I want separate plots. I am able to plot the line plots for each department, but as a single plot using the following piece of code:

```
data = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('hardlines_error.csv')

for label, df in data.groupby('dept'):
    df.residual.plot(  label=label,)
plt.legend()
```

Can someone please tell me how to plot them as separate plots in a grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Seaborn facetgrid.

http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and then [`plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) if need one graph:

```
df = df.pivot(index='date',columns='dept', values='residual')
print (df)
dept         8     12
date                 
4/22/17  100.00  10.1
4/29/17   23.34   NaN
```

Alternative solution:

```
df = df.set_index(['date','dept'])['residual'].unstack()
print (df)
dept         8     12
date                 
4/22/17  100.00  10.1
4/29/17   23.34   NaN


df.plot()
```

But if there are duplicates, get error:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Then need `pivot_table` or `groupby` with aggregate function - check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43974044/2901002).

But if need each graph separately:

```
for i, group in df.groupby('dept'):
    plt.figure()
    group.plot(x='date', y='residual', title=str(i))
```

For grid use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

grouped = df.groupby('dept')

ncols=2
nrows = int(np.ceil(grouped.ngroups/ncols))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, figsize=(12,4), sharey=True)
for (key, ax) in zip(grouped.groups.keys(), axes.flatten()):
    grouped.get_group(key).plot(x='date', y='residual', ax=ax)

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I get this error: `KeyError: 'date'` when I use the last bit of code in your post.

Comment: What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ? Maybe some whitespace like `'  date'`

Comment: That worked, thank you! One more thing. Can you please tell me how to make the plots appear in a grid, and not one underneath the other?