# In python, how to convert list of dates into number of days since first visit?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a list of data showing dates of hospital visits alongside patient ID numbers, data was originally a pandas dataframe which I wrote to a CSV file which now looks similar to this:

```
| Patient |    Date    |
|---------|------------|
|       2 | 17/08/2005 |
|       2 | 07/03/2006 |
|       2 | 27/08/2008 |
|       2 | 22/09/2010 |
|       2 | 20/09/2011 |
|       2 | 01/10/2012 |
|       3 | 13/03/2006 |
|       3 | 12/09/2006 |
|       3 | 12/09/2007 |
|       4 | 18/08/2005 |
|       4 | 03/05/2006 |
|       4 | 25/11/2008 |
|       5 | 23/08/2005 |
|       5 | 09/03/2006 |
|       5 | 06/09/2006 |
```

I want to change the date column to show number of days since that individual patients' first visit, so output will look something like this for the above data -

```
| Patient | Days |
|---------|------|
|       2 |    0 |
|       2 |  202 |
|       2 | 1106 |
|       2 | 1862 |
|       2 | 2225 |
|       2 | 2602 |
|       3 |    0 |
|       3 |  183 |
|       3 |  548 |
|       4 |    0 |
|       4 |  258 |
|       4 | 1195 |
|       5 |    0 |
|       5 |  198 |
|       5 |  379 |
```

Is there an easy way to do this using NumPy/Pandas?  n.b. the overall dataset has about 100,000 visits.

Eventually, I have a 3rd column (for a test carried out at the hospital), and would like to plot (days since last visit) vs (test result) for ~ 5000 patients, on one graph, each patient with their own line.

```
| Patient | Days | Test_result |
|---------|------|-------------|
|       2 |    0 |          28 |
|       2 |  202 |          28 |
|       2 | 1106 |          29 |
|       2 | 1862 |          28 |
|       2 | 2225 |          23 |
|       2 | 2602 |          24 |
|       3 |    0 |          25 |
|       3 |  183 |          28 |
|       3 |  548 |          28 |
|       4 |    0 |          24 |
|       4 |  258 |          20 |
|       4 | 1195 |          24 |
|       5 |    0 |          17 |
|       5 |  198 |          19 |
|       5 |  379 |          27 |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need:

- convert column `Date` [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)
- [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by column `Patient` with `Date` if necessary
- [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and get differences, replace `NaN`s to `0` by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html)
- convert `timedelta`s to days by [`dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html)

---

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.sort_values(['Patient','Date'])
df['Days'] = df.groupby('Patient')['Date'].apply(lambda x: x - x.iat[0]).fillna(0).dt.days
print (df)
    Patient       Date  Days
0         2 2005-08-17     0
1         2 2006-07-03   320
2         2 2008-08-27  1106
3         2 2010-09-22  1862
4         2 2011-09-20  2225
5         2 2012-01-10  2337
6         3 2006-03-13     0
7         3 2006-12-09   271
8         3 2007-12-09   636
9         4 2005-08-18     0
10        4 2006-03-05   199
11        4 2008-11-25  1195
12        5 2005-08-23     0
14        5 2006-06-09   290
13        5 2006-09-03   376
```

**Ploting**

I think 5000 patients is too much, so not nice graph. But if really need it:

Reshape by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) or by [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot.html) and [`plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index(['Patient', 'Days'])['Test_result'].unstack()
print (df1)
Days     0     199   271   290   320   376   636   1106  1195  1862  2225  \
Patient                                                                     
2        28.0   NaN   NaN   NaN  28.0   NaN   NaN  29.0   NaN  28.0  23.0   
3        25.0   NaN  28.0   NaN   NaN   NaN  28.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   
4        24.0  20.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  24.0   NaN   NaN   
5        17.0   NaN   NaN  27.0   NaN  19.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   

Days     2337  
Patient        
2        24.0  
3         NaN  
4         NaN  
5         NaN
```

---

```
df1 = df.pivot(index='Patient', columns='Days', values='Test_result')
print (df1)
Days     0     199   271   290   320   376   636   1106  1195  1862  2225  \
Patient                                                                     
2        28.0   NaN   NaN   NaN  28.0   NaN   NaN  29.0   NaN  28.0  23.0   
3        25.0   NaN  28.0   NaN   NaN   NaN  28.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   
4        24.0  20.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  24.0   NaN   NaN   
5        17.0   NaN   NaN  27.0   NaN  19.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   

Days     2337  
Patient        
2        24.0  
3         NaN  
4         NaN  
5         NaN
```

If get error:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

need `pivot_table` or `groupby` + `aggregate function` + `unstack`, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43974044/2901002).

---

```
df1.plot()
```

EDIT:

Thank you [Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45711973/in-python-how-to-convert-list-of-dates-into-number-of-days-since-first-visit/45712060?noredirect=1#comment78383163_45712060) for alternative solution:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.sort_values(['Patient','Date'])
df['Days'] = df.groupby('Patient')['Date']
               .apply(lambda x: x.diff().dt.days.cumsum()).fillna(0).astype(int)
    Patient       Date  Days
0         2 2005-08-17     0
1         2 2006-07-03   320
2         2 2008-08-27  1106
3         2 2010-09-22  1862
4         2 2011-09-20  2225
5         2 2012-01-10  2337
6         3 2006-03-13     0
7         3 2006-12-09   271
8         3 2007-12-09   636
9         4 2005-08-18     0
10        4 2006-03-05   199
11        4 2008-11-25  1195
12        5 2005-08-23     0
14        5 2006-06-09   290
13        5 2006-09-03   376
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Not sure if it makes any difference, but was pondering `lamba x: x.diff().dt.days.cumsum()` as an alternative...

Comment: That was brilliant, thank you. For the plotting I was having a lot of trouble with the pivot_table function, the table was converted fine but I could not get the key's indexed correctly to plot the correct axes vs index. In the end I plotted the graph iteratively using 'for key,grp in csv_file_variable.groupby('Patient'):
    plt.plot(grp.Days,grp.Test_Result,label = key')

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using `apply`

```
In [178]: df.groupby('Patient').Date.apply(lambda x: x - x.min()).dt.days
Out[178]:
0        0
1      320
2     1106
3     1862
4     2225
5     2337
6        0
7      271
8      636
9        0
10     199
11    1195
12       0
13     376
14     290
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

Details

```
In [179]: df['Days'] = df.groupby('Patient').Date.apply(lambda x: x - x.min()).dt.days

In [180]: df
Out[180]:
    Patient       Date  Days
0         2 2005-08-17     0
1         2 2006-07-03   320
2         2 2008-08-27  1106
3         2 2010-09-22  1862
4         2 2011-09-20  2225
5         2 2012-01-10  2337
6         3 2006-03-13     0
7         3 2006-12-09   271
8         3 2007-12-09   636
9         4 2005-08-18     0
10        4 2006-03-05   199
11        4 2008-11-25  1195
12        5 2005-08-23     0
13        5 2006-09-03   376
14        5 2006-06-09   290
```

Or, use `transform`

```
df.groupby('Patient').Date.transform(lambda x: x - x.min()).dt.days
```