# Pandas - .pivot()

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"ort":["home","away","home","away"]*12, 
  "numbers":np.random.randint(0,3,48),"wins":np.random.randint(99,104,48)})
```

How can I transform `df`to a shape where `ort`becomes a column index, i.e. the shape of the resulting dataframe would look like this

```
| Ort   | Home          |   Away        |
|-------|---------------|---------------|
| Index | numbers wins  |  numbers wins |
| 0     |  0 102        |  2 99         |
| 1     |  2 103        |  1 99         |
```

etc.

I tried `df.pivot(columns = "ort")`which doesn't work because it results in `home and away` being underneath numbers and wins.

Can someone give me a hint how to do it?

I have seen [How to spread a column in a Pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43973999/how-to-spread-a-column-in-a-pandas-data-frame). However my columns "number" and "wins" are just placeholder. In my actual df I have 100 columns (in the link above it is only one column). So my question is how I would then be able to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to spread a column in a Pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43973999/how-to-spread-a-column-in-a-pandas-data-frame)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to introduce a placeholder for game id in order to spread.

```
df['game_id'] = np.array(range(0, len(df.index)//2)).repeat(2)
```

Then this works:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index='game_id', columns='ort',values=['numbers','wins']
               ).swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
#ort        away         home     
#        numbers wins numbers wins
#game_id                          
#0             2  101       2  101
#1             0  100       0   99
#2             1  101       2   99
#3             2  101       2  103
#4             0  103       1  101
#5             0   99       1  102
#...
#23            0  100       1  101
```

Some explanation to follow up on your comment:

- Use `swaplevels(0,1, axis=1)` to swap the levels of the column multiIndex.
- Use `sort_index(axis=1)` to group by the new top-level index (home vs. away).
- If you had a hundred metrics, you would need to replace `['numbers','wins']` with a list of metric names.

Comment: Thanks for your swift support. You solution already helps. Yet, I want away and home as the above row, not numbers and wins. How do I achieve this? Also: what's the best way to do this if I have not only 2 value columns but let's say 100. Thanks!

Comment: Great, thanks! I had to replace "sort" with "sort_index". Then it worked! Thx for you help!

Comment: @Fred true, looks like `sort` is deprecated as of version 18 or earlier.  I edited the answer.