# re-arranging pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

is there to convert the dataframe df

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data=[['a1',2,3],['b1',4,5],['c1',6,7],['a1',8,9],['b1',10,11],['c1',12,13]],columns=['A','B','C'],index=[35,35,35,41,41,41])
df
Out[51]: 
     A   B   C
35  a1   2   3
35  b1   4   5
35  c1   6   7
41  a1   8   9
41  b1  10  11
41  c1  12  13
```

into the dataframe df2?

```
df2=pd.DataFrame(data=[[2,4,6],[3,5,7],[8,10,12],[9,11,13]],columns=['a1','b1','c1'],index=[35,35,41,41])

df2
Out[52]: 
    a1  b1  c1
35   2   4   6
35   3   5   7
41   8  10  12
41   9  11  13
```

Comment: Is "[How to spread a column in a Pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43973999/how-to-spread-a-column-in-a-pandas-data-frame)" helping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a combination of stack and unstack:

```
df.set_index('A', append=True).stack().unstack('A').reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
Out: 
A   a1  b1  c1
35   2   4   6
35   3   5   7
41   8  10  12
41   9  11  13
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: a slightly more generic solution (No guarantee of speed.)

```
df.index.rename("idx", inplace=True)
f = lambda x, col: df.pivot_table(values=col, columns="A", index="idx")
pd.concat(map(f, [df for _ in range(df.shape[1]-1)], df.columns[1:])).sort_index()
```

---

Use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) twice on both column `B` and column `C`. Then use `concat` and finally `sort_index`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['a1',2,3],['b1',4,5],['c1',6,7],['a1',8,9],['b1',10,11],['c1',12,14]],columns=['A','B','C'],index=[35,35,35,41,41,41])

df.index.rename("idx", inplace=True)

df2 = pd.concat([df.pivot_table(values="B", columns="A", index="idx"),
                 df.pivot_table(values="C", columns="A", index="idx")])
df2.sort_index()

 A  a1  b1  c1
idx             
35  2   4   6
35  3   5   7
41  8   10  12
41  9   11  14
```

For illustration, `df.pivot_table(values="C", columns="A", index="idx")` will yield

```
A   a1  b1  c1
idx             
35  3   5   7
41  9   11  14
```

Comment: If my initial dataframe df has more columns (e.g. 45) this approach is rather problematic...