# Flatten a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a csv containing

- one element name and it's value per row
- many elements relate to one sample
- not all samples have all elements
- there are millions of rows

EDIT: Panda Pivot_Table does the generic job of turning unique element names into columns (Thanks @Joe and @Ynjxsjmh).

But how about a units column to go with the elements?

I have made a new column with Element + "_Unit" for the new columns so they are 1 for 1.

If I pivot separately on both I have 2 dataframes the same size so it might be 1 for 1 and could concat them but that is a huge assumption.

```
Sample#,Element,Value,Element_Unit,Unit
222,Ti,0.15,Ti_Unit,%
222,Ag,500,Ag_Unit,ppb
```

to

```
Sample#,Ag,Ag_Unit,Ti,Ti_Unit
222,500,ppb,0.15,%
```

I do not know how to ask this question. Is it an AggFunc question or would a lambda be able to resolve units to elements?

Comment: Look into duckdb

Comment: You want to spread Element column. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43974044/6394617).

Comment: Looks like pivot for me, @ me if it's not.

Comment: Thanks @Joe, this Pivot function looks useful. I will look into it..

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh - there are ~50 possible known elements names but one sample will usually only have 30 at most, some only 1 element. Do I feed all expected element names into the Values and Pivot will assign them if they exist and leave empty if they do not?

Comment: @user24007 Yeah, pivot can use all unique values in `Element` column as column header. If one row `Element` lacks value, it will feed it with NaN.

Comment: @NFeruch - Thanks, duckdb looks interesting but for another time. I am learning the Panda ropes for now.